# NavMesh asset format has changed. Please rebake the NavMesh data

Tags: unity3d

Tentei transformar o jogo em um executável usando o seguinte caminho: `File/Build Settings/Pc,Mac../Build and Run`. Tentei de várias formas diferentes e tenho o mesmo problema: Os inimigos não aparecem.

Dá o seguinte erro (também visível na imagem):

> NavMesh asset format has changed. Please rebake the NavMesh data

[image: Error que aparece logo apos o executavel]

Answer (score -1):

Esse é um erro que acontece quando você migra para a versão 5 do Unity de um projeto antigo.
Não tem nada a ver com caminho ou executável

`NavMesh asset format has changed. Please rebake the NavMesh data` - recomendo mudar o nome do problema para isso.

Você terá que dar outro bake no Navigation, para isso faça:

1. Seleciona o teu `Enviroment` em `Hierarchy`, e clica no static para desmarcar(no Inspector), clique novamente para marcar e escolha para aplicar em todos os filhos. Navigation só funciona para coisas estáticas.
2. Agora vá para o `Navigation` Windows>>>Navigation, ele fica do lado do inspector, e dê um bake de novo.
   Você saberá que está certo quando todo o chão estiver no tom de azul conforme esse vídeo.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRC13neEWZ0&list=PLa2bQ5uCFWA1RNqmaQIAWiq5HiWUGATyC

Comment: Cara, fiz tudo isso, variei a sua dica, mudei até o logar aonde os bichinhos nascem, deixei coloquei outros objetos como static e nada, continua dando o mesmo erro. Os bichinhos até nascem, em alguns lugares, mas não se movem.

Comment: A configuração do Navigation deveria ser a mesma, só de marcar todo o enviroment com static deveria funcionar.
Aparece mais alguma mensagem de erro depois disso?
Dá o play e veja o que está acontecendo no console.