# Problema na hora renderizar o jogo (Nightmare) Jogando com Nils

Tags: unity3d

Estou usando o `Unity 3D versão 5.0.2`. Vou em `"Build Settings..."`para renderizar meu jogo (Projeto Nightmare). 

Porém me parece que não consegue mandar a inteligência artificial dos inimigos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após renderizar, fica esse erro na parte inferior do `Unity 3D`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando inicio o executável do jogo aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro problema que estou tendo é com o tiro esta saindo preto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a tela da configuração do GunBarrelEnd:

Particle system:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado :)

Comment: De uma olhada aqui:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55346/navmesh-asset-format-has-changed-please-rebake-the-navmesh-data